# How to reassign a bitset?

Tags: c++, bitset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // a = 5(0000000101)
    unsigned char a = 5;
 
   bitset<10> y(a);
   cout<<y<<endl;
   
   //Using left shift operator a = 10(0000001010)
   a = a<<1;
   
   bitset<10> z(a);
   cout<<z<<endl;

}
```

I want to set the bitset `y` as the new refreshed bitset since I applied the left shift to `a` and not have to create a new bitset using the constructor every time. (In this case I made a new bitset `z`.)

Is there a way to reassign the value `a` to the bitset?

Comment: [`std::bitset<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)supports an overload for the assignment operator and the copy constructor, what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by _reassign_? You can assign or move stuff. Moving a `bitset` isn't going to make any differance though.

Comment: Why not just do  `y <<= 1;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitsets are [CopyAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable). Simple assignment works:

```
y = a<<1;
```